# Shliach for bedikas chometz -- making another shliach

Tags: halacha, passover, shlichus-agency, home-house, bedikas-chametz

Reuvan went away before Pesach and made Shimon a shliach (emissary) to be bodek (check) his home on lyl yud-daled (the night before Pesach) for chametz. (See beginning of Siman 436 and Mishneh Brurah Sif-Katan 1.)

Can Shimon in turn make Levy a shliach to be bodek the home instead (without asking Reuvan or notifying him of this first)?

Are there any issues with this in halacha? What about the point that perhaps Reuvan wouldn't want anyone else going into his home, aside from the person he appointed? What other points might there be in this halacha in regards to a shliach making another shliach? As always bring sources.